# Allow only alphanumeric and - (dash) symbol in textbox

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I would like to only allow alphabet, special character only a dash (-) and integers in a textbox. And the number i would like to limit them to from 1 to 100. Example A-100

This code allows only numbers to be inserted in the textbox. I want it to allow so that it is something like A-100. Any idea or can someone help to modify this bit of code?

```
<SCRIPT language="Javascript">
function level(evt) {
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;

    return true;
}
</SCRIPT>
```

And I call the event as below to the texbox. Only thing is no special character and alphabets it only allows integers.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" Width="200px" onkeypress="return level(event)" placeholder="Insert level number" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: What does it have to do with c#?

Comment: you need to clarify what you are looking for.    e.g., how many alpha and numeric sequences are allowed.  Is `A100B100` allowed, for example, or will it only be `An`, where A is a single alpha character and n is a number from 1 to 100?

Comment: @ps2goat i am looking for one alphabet in the front from A-Z then followed by a (-) dash and then integers from 1 to 100. example A-100 or B-72 or C-56. Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: Explain what you want *in the question itself* and show your best effort so far at doing it. As this is about client-side scripting, refer to HTML and JavaScript, not to server-side issues and code unless they are essential (and if they are, explain how).